# Detect leaky connection on Azure Sql Databases

Tags: sql-server, connection-pooling, azure-sql-database

I have a very busy application that hums along just fine with about 10 - 20 connections (via sp_who2), but occasionally connections will spike (300 - 500), and Azure Sql Database will start terminating them. This kills the application. It happened very infrequently, but more so now that we added the third application.

There are currently 4 different applications hitting the database - an admin site, and three different instances of the application.

So, without Sql Server Profiler, how does one determine where the leak is coming from?

As an aside, the application uses primarily Entity Framework 6, but some of the more complicated / heavily used data access methods use some custom stored procedures and ado.net code. Here's an example, in case anyone can determine if this is a potential issue:

```
public Content FindContent(int id)
{
    Content content = null;
    using (SqlCommand command = CreateProcedure("dbo.FindContent"))
    {
        AddParam(command, "Id", SqlDbType.Int, id);

        var results = ExecuteReader<Content, Content, ContentFile>(command, x => BindContent(x), x => BindContent(x), x => BindContentFile(x));
        if (results.Result1.Count > 0)
        {
            content = results.Result1[0];
            content.AttachRelatedItems(results.Result2);
            content.Files = results.Result3;
        }
    }
    return content;
}
```

BindContent and BindContentFile are functions executed with the results. They just loop the reader and build up the collection.

This calls a generic ExecuteReader method, which processes three resultsets from the procedure:

```
private ThreeResults<T1, T2, T3> ExecuteReader<T1, T2, T3>(SqlCommand command, Func<SqlDataReader, T1> rowConverter1, Func<SqlDataReader, T2> rowConverter2, Func<SqlDataReader, T3> rowConverter3)
{
    ThreeResults<T1, T2, T3> resultsets = new ThreeResults<T1, T2, T3>();
    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(this.ConnectionString))
    {
        command.Connection = connection;
        connection.Open();
        using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
        {
            List<T1> ret1 = new List<T1>();
            List<T2> ret2 = new List<T2>();
            List<T3> ret3 = new List<T3>();
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                ret1.Add(rowConverter1(reader));
            }

            reader.NextResult();
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                ret2.Add(rowConverter2(reader));
            }

            reader.NextResult();
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                ret3.Add(rowConverter3(reader));
            }

            resultsets.Result1 = ret1;
            resultsets.Result2 = ret2;
            resultsets.Result3 = ret3;

            reader.Close();
        }
    }
    return resultsets;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For the EF6 parts of the application, you can use the built in connection resiliency to deal with this https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/dn456835.

Comment: I don't think retrying a connection when the database is refusing connections is going to work.